# Only print first and second word of each line to output with sed

Tags: awk, sed

I want to clean up a pattern file for later use, so only the first and second word (or number) are relevant.

I have this:

**pattern.txt**

```
# This is a test pattern
some_variable        one    # placeholder which replaces a variable
some_other_var 2    # other variable to replace
# Some random comment in between
different_var "hello"   # this will also replace a placeholder but with a string
    



# And after some empty lines:
  var_after_newlines        18          # some variable after a lot of newlines


{{hello}} " this is just a string surrounded by space "

{bello} "this is just a string"#and this is a comment

cello "#string with a comment in it"#and a comment
```

To which I apply:

`sed -nE '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;s/^\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+).*$/\1 \2/p' pattern.txt > output.txt`

- it should clean out comment lines starting with # -> works
- it should clean out empty lines (or lines with whitespace characters) -> works
- it should replace every line with its first and second word seperated by one (1) space character -> doesn't work. Compare:

**output.txt**

Expectation:

```
some_variable one
some_other_var 2
different_var "hello"
var_after_newlines 18
{{hello}} " this is just a string surrounded by space "
{bello} "this is just a string"
cello "#string with a comment in it"
```

Reality:

```
different_var "hello"   # thi
  var_after_newline
{{hello}} " thi
{bello} "thi
cello "#
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

As @Ed Morton pointed out, it would make sense to als include the following cases: strings with spaces, strings with spaces before and after quotation marks, comments within strings and comments right after the quotation mark. The accepted answers sed solution works fine with all of this.

Comment: What should be printed if there is only 1 "word" on the line? What should be printed if the line is just `var # 1 word and a comment`? What if the line was `var " string surrounded with space "`? What if it was `var "#string surrounded by#"`? Please [edit] your example to include those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU `sed`

```
sed -E '/^\s*(#.*)?$/d; s/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/\1 \2/' pattern.txt
```

---

Update after the comments:

```
sed -E '/^\s*(#.*)?$/d; s/^\s*(\S+)\s+("[^"]*"|\S+).*/\1 \2/' pattern.txt
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I just checked if it would also work with whole string replacements like i want to replace:
{{hello}} "it worked, hello world!"
But this only puts ```"it``` in the corresponding places. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: @glades I didn't understand thoroughly. Is it possible to give a sample line and expected output?

Comment: Sure, Input would be something like ```{{hello}} "this is just a string" # some string``` which consists of two columns {{hello}} and "this is just a string". Expected output would be ```{{hello}} "this is just a string"``` with the comment removed, but note that the stringy bit is sepereated by the spaces with the current solution which is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Completely based on your shown samples only, this could be easily done with `awk`. Written and tested with GNU `awk`, should work with any `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NF && !/^#/{print $1,$2}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking 2 conditions here. 1st- `NF` which makes sure line is NOT empty line. 2nd- Line is NOT starting with # then print 1st and 2nd columns of current line.

---

---

***With `sed`:*** Please try following in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/\r$//;/^#/d;/^\s*$/d;s/^ +//;s/([^ ]*) +([^ ]*).*/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

OR as per Ed sir's comments use following:

```
sed -E 's/\r$//; /^#/d; /^\s*$/d; s/^\s+//; s/(\S*)\s+(\S*).*/\1 \2/' Input_file
```

Sample output is as follows for both above solutions:

```
some_variable one
some_other_var 2
different_var "hello"
var_after_newlines 18
```

Comment: This works flawlessly thanks. And I have been pulling my hairs trying to understand sed. Do you know how it would have looked like with sed?

Comment: @glades, sure, please try following with GNU `sed` once: `sed -E '/^#/d;/^\s*$/d;s/^ +//;s/([^ ]*) +([^ ]*).*/\1 \2/' Input_file` and  let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That doesn't quite do the job. It still contains '#' and tabs

Comment: @glades, For me both `sed` and `awk` solutions have worked fine and are giving same results to be honest.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using linux? I'm using git bash on Windows, maybe that's the difference. For example, for the first line I'm getting:
```some_variable   one``` which still contains a tab and spaces
Second line gives:
```some_other_var 2 #```

Comment: @glades, yes I am using Linux and GNU `sed`, it worked fine for me. Could you please do one test for me by doing `cat -v Your_file` once to see if you see Control M characters in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229897/discussion-between-glades-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @glades, I have added Logic of removing control M characters too in code, please do check updated codes and let me know if All is Well, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Version that should work with most any `sed`:

```sh
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//; s/#.*//; /^$/d; s/^\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1 \2/' pattern.txt
some_variable one
some_other_var 2
different_var "hello"
var_after_newlines 18
```